# How can you build a custom endpoint on another website?

Tags: api, endpoints

I am trying to get used to flask but I want to basically create a custom endpoint.

For example: 
given a website is called: abc.com
I basically want to create an endpoint: abc.com/me
which would then print something like "HI"

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctyly, this peace of code is what you want to do.
When you run the code servers up and run on the localhost:5000 in default port, if you route localhost:5000/me page shows hi. also read [documantation](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/me') 
def me():
    return 'Hi'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```